# nodejs: create same value in a short period

Tags: node.js

I have a sample app, user can access some dynamic data via different URL.

The workflow is like this:

1. when user request `get_data?id=1234567`
2. first it checks the DB if there is data for it
3. if not, generate a random value
4. then if other users request the same url within a short time (say 10 min), it will return the value that already generated
5. if one of the users send a clear request, the value will be cleared from DB.

The bug is: if 2 users request the same url at the same time, since it needs time to query the DB, it would do 1 and 2 at the same time, then create different values for each user.

How to make sure that in a short period, it always generate same value for all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although NodeJS is single threaded and does not have the problem of synchronization between multiple threads, its asynchronous event model still can require you to implement some kind of locking mechanism to synchronize the concurrent async operations in certain situations (like in your case).

There are a number of libraries that provide this functionality, e.g. [async-mutex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-mutex). Here's a very basic example of what your code could look like:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Mutex = require('async-mutex').Mutex;

const locks = new Map();

app.get('/get_data', async (req, res) => {
    const queryId = req.query.id;
    if (!queryId) {
        // handle empty queryid ...
    }
    if (!locks.has(queryId)) {
        locks.set(queryId, new Mutex());
    }
    const lockRelease = await locks
        .get(queryId)
        .acquire();
    try {
        // do the rest of your logic here
    } catch (error) {
        // handle error
    } finally {
        // always release the lock
        lockRelease();
    }

});


app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log("Server is running at port 4000");
});
```

Comment: thanks. just got some time to test this, I will let you know once I got something.